# How can computer clouds charge me for CPU usage?

Tags: cpu-usage, cloud, google-app-engine, azure

I’m considering moving my blog to either MS Azure or Google App Engine, using either an ASP.NET or Python blogging engine, but I can’t understand how they will charge me for CPU usage. The bandwidth and storage charges seem straightforward, but not the CPU...

According to the services' respective documentation, I will pay either $0.12 or $0.10 for an hour of CPU usage. Does that mean I will be charged approximately `30 days * 24h * $0.12 = $86.40` monthly *regardless* of the number of visitors and the complexity of my code? Will I pay the same CPU price when I have 2 visitors a day as when I have one thousand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google App Engine charges for actual CPU time, as implied by their partial unit FAQ answer:

http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/billing.html#rounding

Comment: do you know if azure has similar model of charging

Comment: Azure appears to charge for deployed-time, even if the instance is idle, judging from this: "Compute time, measured in machine hours: Windows Azure compute hours are charged only for when your application is deployed. When developing and testing your application, developers will want to remove the compute instances that are not being used to minimize compute hour billing."

Answer (score 3):

No it depends on the number of CPU hours you actually use. If one visitor's request requires 1 second of calculation, 1 visitor per day will cost you $.12/3600 daily, 3600 visitors/day costs $.12/day, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, When someone charges you on CPU - it for actuall use of the cpu by a process that serves your app.